# Downloading from API using python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I work for a firm and for a project I need to download a dataset on daily basis from the company's API. Each API is defined by a Feed ID. I can generate a URL, which when I run on the browser, it downloads the latest Excel file. I need the data in that Excel file. On a daily basis, I should read the content of the file in Python's data frame and do some calculations on it. Here is the code that I use now.

```
import requests
url = 'XXXX.getDataSetByFeedId?feedId={}'.format(
               feed_id)
r = requests.get(url=url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, passwd))
```

When I print `r`, It is not a dataset, It is just a text saying that the request is successful.
I tried:

```
r.json()
```

But it gives me an error

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: is `XXXX.getDataSetByFeedId` a valid URL?

Comment: Yes it is. I deleted the first part for security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the file as binary content. You cannot convert it to JSON, that's why you get the error. Try this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('XXXX.getDataSetByFeedId', params={'feedId': feed_id}, auth=(username, passwd))

filename = '{}.xlsx'.format(feed_id)

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I define the parameter file.xlsx?